# Ruby module that delegates methods to an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, metaprogramming

I have an AR object called Run that keeps information of when the run was started, ended, disabled, etc. I am trying to create a class Something and want to make it "runnable". So I created a module called `Runnable` that takes in a run object on initialization. Now say I mix in this module into a class `Something`. I want the something object to delegate all the methods defined on run to the run object.

```
module Runnable
  def initialize(run)
    @run = run
  end

  def self.method_missing(name, *args)
    super unless @run.respond_to?(name)
    @run.send(name, args)
  end
end

class Something
  include Runnable
end
```

Now if I do:

```
run = Run.find(123)
run.start_date # works!
something = Something.new(run)
something.start_date # NoMethodError: undefined method `start_date' for #<Something:0x007fb4a276b0c0>
```

Any idea what I am missing? Is there a better way of doing what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two mistakes:

- `method_missing` needs to be an instance method, not a class method
- `@run.send(name, args)` should be `@run.send(name, *args)`. The former results in `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)` when `Run#start_date` is executed.

```
class Run
  def start_date
    "Any time now"
  end
end

module Runnable
  def initialize(run)
    @run = run
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args)
    super unless @run.respond_to?(name)
    @run.send(name, *args)
  end
end

class Something
  include Runnable
end

run = Run.new
run.start_date
  #=> "Any time now"
something = Something.new(run)
  #=> #<Something:0x00000002642100 @run=#<Run:0x0000000266d558>>
something.start_date 
  #=> "Any time now"
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me a [SimpleDelegator](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html) would achieve what you are looking for here.

Comment: I thought about that but I can't use that in modules, can I?

Comment: Not sure why you want a module here though. You define initialize in it, it seems that this will not be a very flexible module. Why not using inheritance and do `class Something < Runnable` ?

Comment: Because I have only one shot at inheriting from a class. Once my `Something` class inherits from `Runnable`, it cannot inherit from anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Forwardable` for now

```
module Runnable
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegator :@run, :start_date, :end_date

  def initialize(run)
    @run = run
  end
end
```